# org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class A

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I am using SimpleXML to serialize(write to XML) without any problem. But, when I try to read and deserialize to XML I get following exception. I am using lombok plugin to give constructors such as " @RequiredArgsConstructor".

The error message is : "org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Constructor not matched for class A".

If you want I can provide codes for more detailed information

Comment: Looks like you are trying to call a constructor either with arguments that don't match the class or using a default constructor that does not exist.

Answer (score 13):

Does the class `A` have a constructor *without* arguments? Those are needed for deserialization (can private though).

If you have only constructors with argument, the serializer can't create default constructed objects on reading. As this is not necessary on writing, you don't get the error there.